# getline() equivalent in Swift

Tags: swift, csv

I am trying to make an app that can look through a csv file and display the results. I don't know how to put the csv file in an array of strings. Is there an equivalent of getline() from C++ in Swift? In C++, I have this code:
`getline(myFile,cell,',')` where myFile is an ifstream file and cell is where the data is going to get stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're okay with using standard input, Swift has a `readLine()` function built in. You can then use `split`:

```
let line = "a,b,c"
let fields = line.characters.split(",").map(String.init)
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, `readLine()` reads *only* from the standard input.

Answer (score 4):

You can use getline() in Swift. Just `import Darwin` and you can use it. Swift only has readLine() which has more limited functionality.